# pyspark for loop to iter with row values

Tags: pyspark

I have below code in R and I am trying to convert it to equivalent pyspark code, but after conversion my intended results are differing. Could anyone please guide me what is going wrong here.

The R code is as below

```
# loop through all  values, from the lowest to the highest
for (i in 1:nrow(values)){
  # select all pairs whose weights are >= currently processed weight
  tmp <- data_int[vote >= values[i, vote]]
```

and I am converting it into pyspark as

```
result = []

for row in values.collect():
    tmp = data_int.filter(data_int.vote >= values.vote)
```

Can anyone guide me how to convert it to achieve desire operation in pyspark

input dataframe data_int is

```
col1  col2  vote
12     567   0.2
23     568   0.9
14     254   0.38
21     258   0.89
```

values dataframe  is

```
vote
 0.3
0.9
0.80
0.36
```

and tmp (Desired output is)
tmp :

```
col1  col2  vote
23     568   0.9
14     254   0.38
21     258   0.89
```

Comment: In the pyspark code you are iterating through each row of the values dataframe, but in each iteration you are not utilising the row at all. Is this a mistake only here while publishing the question or in your code as well? Anyway this will not solve your problem anyway, you need to join these two tables together to apply the filter correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to utilize the row but I dont know how can i do it. If you can help with.Also join will not help as I want to select records which are greater than in values dataframe

Comment: I'm not used to R, but why do you need to loop? Can't you just use the smallest value of the `values` and call the filter?